# Flutter hot reloading with VSCode sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: flutter, dart

The title says it all. Here's a [gif demonstrating](https://gifyu.com/image/lfdz). Some changes to code the UI gets updated as expected whereas at other times the updates aren't reflected.

This prompt in VSCode **does not** mean that the app has hot reloaded.

> Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86."

Heres my `main.dart` file that has the two lists I want to flip for reference.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // List<Color> colors = [Colors.yellow, Colors.red, Colors.yellow];
  List<Color> colors = [Colors.red, Colors.white, Colors.blue];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: colors
                .map((element) => Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: element),
                      // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: _counter.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.blue),
                    )))
                .toList()),
      ),
  }
}
```

Please advise me on how to get the VScode hot reloading to work when I do `command+s`.

When I move `colors` out of the state of the _MyHomePageStatte Widget, the behavior is the same. Here's the [gif demo](https://gifyu.com/image/lfuO)

Comment: Global variables and static fields are treated as state, and are therefore not reinitialized during hot reload, this means if you change a global variable as it is the case of this example the hot reload will not happen. Nor are variables used in initstate, you can find more here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update a member variable in a stateful widget, you must hot restart the app or close and reopen the widget

And to make the hot reload working with the variable outside of the widget, you must use `const varName` instead of `final varName` or `<Type> varName`. If the variable cannot be converted to const then you have no option than hot restart the app

Answer (score 0):

it's because first color changed is a variable, when you save hot reload apply the new color, but when you change the second variable, it's a variable in your state, hot reload change your variables but the state of your widget dosn't change, it 's not a probleme it's normal. If you want to see your change you can reload your application.

Comment: I updated my question. When I move colors out of the state of the Widget the changes still aren't reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Only the Variables which are inside build or updated inside build are impacted through hot reload,

If you want to change variable outside build or reload the state you must consider hot restart.